# Cron Job task not executing python script on server with virtual environment

Tags: ssh, cron, cron-task, python-venv

I'm connecting to the server via SSH. In my project I have a `/scripts` folder in which I have my python script I want to run. In order to execute it, I have to activate my virtual environment first (I have my `venv` folder in the /scripts folder). I have tried scheduling several different Cron jobs to do this but none have worked to execute the script. I know the tasks are being executed since they are being logged in `/var/log/syslog`.

What I have tried so far is:

`* * * * * cd /path/to/project/ && source /path/to/project/scripts/venv/bin/activate && /path/to/project/scripts/script_to_run.py arguments
* * * * * python /path/to/project/scripts/script_to_run.py arguments
* * * * * /path/to/project/scripts/venv/bin/python /path/to/project/scripts/script_to_run.py arguments
* * * * * /usr/bin/python && source /path/to/project/scripts/venv/bin/activate && /path/to/project/scripts/script_to_run.py arguments`

(I am not trying to run everything at every minute, just put * * * * * at the beginning of every task here).

I have also tried making a .sh script and making a cron job for that (and attempting to log the errors in `cronjob.log`, but that didn't work either):

`* * * * * bash /path/to/project/scripts/script.sh >/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1`

**script.sh**:

`#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/project/scripts/venv/bin/activate
python /path/to/project/scripts/script_to_run.py arguments`

It is executable and it worked running it from the terminal.

My project directory:

`project
    scripts
        venv
            bin
                activate
                python
        script_to_run.py
        script.sh`

Comment: Maybe this works: add a line `DISPLAY=:0` to the top of your script.sh?

Comment: As an aside: If script.sh is executable, you can omit the `bash` in front of it, in the crontab file.

Comment: Make sure your /path/to/project really starts with a forward slash `/`, in other words, that it is a true absolute path.

Comment: Also you migth want to add the following two lines near the top of your crontab file:`SHELL=/bin/bash` and `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:`